# Action is being performed three times

Tags: button, arduino, monitor

I am creating an Arduino project that plays Rock Paper Scissors.
I have a part of the code reading the value of the button and whenever I click only one button, it outputs three times (View code and images of serial monitor to understand what I mean, I can't really explain it)

Here is my code:

```
// constants won't change. They're used here to 
// set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin1 = A0;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int buttonPin2 = A1;
const int buttonPin3 = A2;
const int ledPin =  12;      // the number of the LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState1 = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int buttonState2 = 0; 
int buttonState3 = 0; 

char * choices[3] = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};
char * finalResult[3] = {"You Lost", "You Won!", "It's a Tie"};

byte Human = 0, Computer = 0, FR = 0;

char result[25];

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin3, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  unsigned long R;
  randomSeed(R);
}

void loop(){
  int choice = random(1,4);
  int pick;
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:


  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  Serial.println("Entering Reading Loop...");
  while(true)
  {
    buttonState1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);
    buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);
    buttonState3 = digitalRead(buttonPin3);
    if (buttonState1 == HIGH && buttonState2 == LOW && buttonState3 == LOW) {     
      // turn LED on:    
      Throw('1');

    } else if (buttonState1 == LOW && buttonState2 == HIGH && buttonState3 == LOW) {     
      // turn LED on:    
      pick = 2; //Paper
      Throw('2');

    }else if (buttonState1 == LOW && buttonState2 == LOW && buttonState3 == HIGH) {     
      // turn LED on:    
      pick = 3; //Scissor
      Throw('3');

    }

  }
}

void Throw(char H)
{
  bool thrown = false;
  H -= '0'; //convert ascii to decimal
  H -= 1; // instead of  1,2,3, H is now 0,1,2

  byte C = random(0, 3);

  sprintf(result, "The Computer chose: %s, You chose: %s", choices[C], choices[H]);
  Serial.println(result);

  if ( C == H)
    Serial.println(F("Its a TIE"));
  else
  {
    switch (C)
    {
      case 0:
        switch (H)
        {
          case 1:
            Serial.println(F("Paper wraps Rock, You WIN!"));
            Human++;
            break;

          case 2:
            Serial.println(F("Rock crushes Scissors, You LOSE!"));
            Computer++;
            break;
        }
        break;

      case 1:
        switch (H)
        {
          case 0:
            Serial.println(F("Paper wraps Rock, You LOSE!"));
            Computer++;
            break;

          case 2:
            Serial.println(F("Scissors cuts Paper, You WIN!"));
            Human++;
            break;
        }
        break;

      case 2:
        switch (H)
        {
          case 0:
            Serial.println(F("Rock crushes Scissors, You WIN!"));
            Human++;
            break;

          case 1:
            Serial.println(F("Scissors cuts Paper, You LOSE!"));
            Computer++;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I'm getting on the serial monitor when I click only ONE button(the rock button)

http://gyazo.com/ceb5c8329993339368cf5d52181ed4d7

As you can see, it chooses the right option for the button but it calls the throw function 3 times.

http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RockPaperScissors)

Answer (score 0):

From the Arduino docs they recommend using a Debounce strategy for handling inputs.

> Without debouncing, pressing the button once can appear to the code as
>   multiple presses.

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce

Here is another example illustrating the Debounce technique:

http://danthompsonsblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/arduino-push-button-onoff-example.html

Comment: Here is my circuit https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwgpj32y8nwy7zr/20150424_182514.jpg?dl=0

I have the pulldown resistor Do I need to edit my code? , and if so how?

Comment: The above links are more to do with code changes, and they illustrate the concept better than I could. One key element is that once a button press occurs they are saving the `lastButtonState`, then when the next loop occurs they don't do anything if the next button read is the same as the lastButtonState.

Comment: I added the code changes and still does output 3 times, is there something wrong with the function?

Answer (score 0):

There are pull-up resistors built in to the arduino that will allow you to filter out the erratic electrical signal you get when pressing a button. See the section on [INPUT_PULLUP here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins).

Comment: I have a pull down resistor in my circuit, dropbox.com/s/hwgpj32y8nwy7zr/20150424_182514.jpg?dl=0

I think its a code issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't what the exact issue was but, I added a delay in my throw function and it stopped outputting the serial print statement 3 times!

Here is my updated function:

```
void Throw(char H)
{
  bool thrown = false;
  H -= '0'; //convert ascii to decimal
  H -= 1; // instead of  1,2,3, H is now 0,1,2

  byte C = random(0, 3);

  sprintf(result, "The Computer chose: %s, You chose: %s", choices[C], choices[H]);
  Serial.println(result);
  delay(500);


  if ( C == H)
    Serial.println(F("Its a TIE"));
  else
  {
    switch (C)
    {
      case 0:
        switch (H)
        {
          case 1:
            Serial.println(F("Paper wraps Rock, You WIN!"));

            Human++;
            break;
            return;

          case 2:
            Serial.println(F("Rock crushes Scissors, You LOSE!"));

            Computer++;
            break;
        }
        break;

      case 1:
        switch (H)
        {
          case 0:
            Serial.println(F("Paper wraps Rock, You LOSE!"));

            Computer++;
            break;

          case 2:
            Serial.println(F("Scissors cuts Paper, You WIN!"));

            Human++;
            break;
        }
        break;

      case 2:
        switch (H)
        {
          case 0:
            Serial.println(F("Rock crushes Scissors, You WIN!"));

            Human++;
            break;

          case 1:
            Serial.println(F("Scissors cuts Paper, You LOSE!"));

            Computer++;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```